# Excel Format cell with numbers automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am using Excel for Office O365 16.0.11929

I have the issue with formating cells to numbers format when I copied some data from other application (i am using navision 2009r2)

The values with numbers are copied as general and I need them to be a number format

What I can do to convert cell with numbers to Number format automatically?

When I tried to copy with "special" I got below option but it's not working for me, the numbers are still at the general format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making use of the information box that Excel provides. Here all the numbers are in text format and hence their alignment is towards left in the cell:

[image]

Now, I will copy the column A and paste in the Column A of Sheet2. They are still present in Text format.

Now, select the whole column by clicking on column name *i.e.* **'A'**. At the first cell, you will see a information box as highlighted below. Click on "Convert to Number" and there you go, all those numbers are converted to 'Number' format, aligned towards right:

[image]

Now you can operate on them without having to worry about them being in text format. I hope this helps :)